# Highcharts hide not active series from legend when taking screenshot

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

Is it somehow possible to hide all inactive series from legend when taking screenshot?

For example I have chart like this :

[image]

But what I want have on picture is this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap `exportChart` method and set `showInLegend` property to `false` on invisible series:

```
var H = Highcharts;

H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'exportChart', function(proceed, exportingOptions) {
    var series = this.series;

    Highcharts.each(series, function(s) {
        if (s.visible) {
            s.update({
                showInLegend: true
            }, false);
        } else {
            s.update({
                showInLegend: false
            }, false);
        }
    });

    // which are sliced off this function's arguments
    proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

    Highcharts.each(series, function(s) {
        s.update({
            showInLegend: true
        }, false);
    });

    this.redraw();
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cgj9vwas/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
series: [{
            showInLegend: false,
            name: 'Series',
            data: value                
        }]
```